# Django on Heroku - settings.py for development vs. production

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I deployed a django application to Heroku using [this tut](http://www.ashrafulabedein.com/deploy-django-heroku/).

And I know I can use `heroku local` to run the app locally.

**But how do I migrate locally?** as in create a database **locally**, not in the cloud, rather than push changes to the cloud and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the `DATABASES` setting for your local environment to point to a different database:

```
# settings.py

. . .


# at the end
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass


# local_settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'whatever',
        'USER': 'whatever',
        'PASSWORD': 'your-password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Comment: And once your settings point to a local database, you migrate by running `./manage.py migrate`.